# Selenoid Failed to start

Tags: selenoid

I am absolutely new in selenoid 
Try to start selenoid using this command: `./cm selenoid start --vnc`
& get this error:

> root@ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-fra1-01:~# ./cm selenoid start --vnc
>   Using Docker
>   - Your Docker API version is 1.38
>   Selenoid is already downloaded
>   Selenoid is already configured
>   Starting Selenoid...
>   x Failed to start: failed to start container: Error response from daemon: error while creating mount source path '/root/.aerokube/selenoid/video': mkdir /root/.aerokube/selenoid/video: permission denied

Comment: What else have you tried? What are you trying to achieve and what are you expecting to see?

Comment: Improved Formatting

Answer (score 1):

To run selenoid on your VM machine please follow below step:

Run below command in your VM.

1) Download CM package 
           run this command in your ubuntu console:- **curl -s https://aerokube.com/cm/bash**

1.5) Give permission to your **cm** folder: chmod +x cm

2) Now you need to start selenoid using this.
           command:- **./selenoid start**

3) Download latest firefox & chrome image from docker 
          command : **docker pull selenoid/chrome:80.0** or **docker pull selenoid/firefox**

4) To up selenoid-ui service you can this command: .**/cm selenoid-ui start**

selenoid endpoint:- http://localhost:4444/wd/hub (localhost:vm instance ip address)

selenoid-Ui endpoint:- http://localhost:8080

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use

```
  docker-compose.yml
```

https://github.com/aerokube/selenoid/blob/master/docs/docker-compose.adoc

Also it was another question how to run it

[TestNG docker-compose can not find localhost url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64973227/testng-docker-compose-can-not-find-localhost-url/65085614#65085614)