# TestNG docker-compose can not find localhost url

Tags: docker-compose, dockerfile

I have this docker-compose configuration

```
version: '3'
services:
  selenoid:
    image: "aerokube/selenoid:latest"
    container_name: selenoid
    ports:
      - "0.0.0.0:4444:4444"
    networks:
      - selenoid
    volumes:
      - ".:/etc/selenoid"
      - "./target:/output"
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock"
      - "./target:/opt/selenoid/video"
    environment:
      - "OVERRIDE_VIDEO_OUTPUT_DIR=$PWD/target"
    command: ["-limit", "10", "-conf", "/etc/selenoid/browsers.json", "-video-output-dir", "/opt/selenoid/video", "-container-network", "selenoid"]
  selenoid-ui:
    image: "aerokube/selenoid-ui:latest"
    container_name: selenoid-ui
    links:
      - selenoid
    ports:
      - "8083:8080"
    networks:
      - selenoid
    command: ["--selenoid-uri", "http://selenoid:4444"]
  chrome_79.0:
    image: "selenoid/vnc:chrome_79.0"
    container_name: chrome_79.0
    links:
      - selenoid
      - selenoid-ui
    depends_on:
      - selenoid
      - selenoid-ui
    networks:
      - selenoid
    volumes:
      - "/dev/shm:/dev/shm"
  sent:
    image: "sent:1.0"
    container_name: sent
    links:
      - selenoid
      - selenoid-ui
    depends_on:
      - selenoid
      - selenoid-ui
    networks:
      - selenoid
networks:
  selenoid:
    external:
      name: selenoid
```

send is a container that runs TestNG tests, but looks like can not find localhost URL.

If I check the open ports I see this

```
chrome_79.0   /entrypoint.sh                   Up                      4444/tcp              
selenoid      /usr/bin/selenoid -listen  ...   Up                      0.0.0.0:4444->4444/tcp
selenoid-ui   /selenoid-ui --selenoid-ur ...   Up (health: starting)   0.0.0.0:8083->8080/tcp
```

And I can access localhost:4444 from outside, but even the container is in the same network can not access localhost.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I little bit change your docker file and it works =)

1. **Remove chrome_79.0 and everything what is under**

Because you can execute download chrome image directly:

```
docker pull selenoid/vnc:chrome_79.0
```

2. **Remove all your "networks"  (also from command section)**

   ```
   networks:
      -selenoid
   ```

and add instead (**don't add in command section**)

```
 network_mode: bridge
```

i.e

```
image: "aerokube/selenoid:latest"    
network_mode: bridge
    .
    .
    .
image: "aerokube/selenoid-ui:latest"
network_mode: bridge
```

3.**Before record video I suggest you to see how it works without recording...**

Just change volumes section.
I use Mac and in my situation it looks like

```
 volumes: 
  - "$PWD:/etc/selenoid"
  - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock"
  - "$PWD:/opt/selenoid/logs"
```

4.**Execute**

```
  docker-compose up
  docker pull selenoid/vnc:chrome_79.0
```

5.**See list of images and containers**

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                         COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                 PORTS                    NAMES
ef60d57bc743        aerokube/selenoid-ui:latest   "/selenoid-ui --sele…"   2 hours ago         Up 2 hours (healthy)   0.0.0.0:8083->8080/tcp   selenoid-ui
05bf58b73f53        aerokube/selenoid:latest      "/usr/bin/selenoid -…"   2 hours ago         Up 2 hours             0.0.0.0:4444->4444/tcp   selenoid

REPOSITORY             TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
aerokube/selenoid-ui   latest              71ad7fb4efa7        5 days ago          17.5MB
aerokube/selenoid      latest              b8f47d114751        11 days ago         16.3MB
selenoid/vnc           chrome_65.0         dff07a4cfe6d        2 years ago         959MB
```

6.**Open**

```
http://localhost:8083
```

Fun

PS. If not working ask me directly.